# Sum of a non arithmetic nor geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Express the following sum as a common fraction:
$\frac{1}{1\cdot4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot7}+\frac{1}{7\cdot10}+\frac{1}{10\cdot13}+...+\frac{1}{97\cdot100}$

This is from a timed competition, so fastest answers are best.
I tried rearranging it to
$$\frac{7\cdot10\cdot13\cdot...\cdot100+1\cdot10\cdot13\cdot...\cdot100+...+1\cdot4\cdot7\cdot...\cdot 94}{1\cdot4\cdot7\cdot10\cdot13\cdot...\cdot100}$$but I don't know what to do after this. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the sum as $$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{32}\frac1{3k+1}\frac1{3k+4}&
=\frac13\sum_{k=0}^{32}\left(\frac1{3k+1}-\frac1{3k+4}\right)\\
&=\frac13\left(1-\frac1{100}\right)\\
&=\frac{33}{100}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{n(n+3)}=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3})$$

$$\frac{1}{1\cdot4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot7}+\frac{1}{7\cdot10}+\frac{1}{10\cdot13}+...+\frac{1}{97\cdot100}=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{10}+...+\frac{1}{97}-\frac{1}{100})=\frac{1}{3}(1-\frac{1}{100})=\frac{33}{100}$$